# How to get only the date value from a Windows Forms DateTimePicker control?

Tags: c#, winforms, date, datetimepicker

I'm building an application with C# code.
How do I get only the date value from a `DateTimePicker` control?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean a datetime picker in a winforms application.

in your code, you can do the following:

```
string theDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

or, if you'd like to specify the format of the date:

```
string theDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: So I've used yyyy-mm-dd instead of yyyy-MM-dd and was struggling why I get a random month every time I was trying to get a date :D

Answer (score 52):

```
DateTime dt = this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
```

Comment: yes, but it picks 12:00 AM instead of the current time, and thus does the job.

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue when inserting date data into a database, you can simply use the struct members separately:
In my case it's useful since the sql sentence needs to have the right values and you just need to add the slash or dash to complete the format, no conversions needed.

```
DateTimePicker dtp = new DateTimePicker();
String sql = "insert into table values(" + dtp.Value.Date.Year + "/" + 
dtp.Value.Date.Month + "/" + dtp.Value.Date.Day + ");";
```

That way you get just the date members without time...

Answer (score 5):

```
string shortDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 4):

Following that this question has been already given a good answer, in WinForms we can also set a [Custom Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the *DateTimePicker* [Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property as Vivek said, this allow us to display the date/time in the specified format string within the *DateTimePicker*, then, it will be simple just as we do to get text from a *TextBox*.

```
// Set the Format type and the CustomFormat string.
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;    
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd";
```

[image: dateTimePicker1]

We are now able to get Date only easily by getting the Text from the *DateTimePicker*:

```
MessageBox.Show("Selected Date: " + dateTimePicker1.Text, "DateTimePicker", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

[image]

NOTE: If you are planning to insert Date only data to a **date** column type in SQL, see this [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) related to the supported String Literal Formats for **date**. You can not insert a date in the format string **ydm** because is not supported:

```
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy/dd/MM";  
var qr = "INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (@dtp)";
using (var insertCommand = new SqlCommand..
{
   try
   {
     insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtp", dateTimePicker1.Text);
     con.Open();
     insertCommand.ExecuteScalar();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Exception message: " + ex.Message, "DateTimePicker", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
   }
```

the above code ends in the following Exception:
[image]

Be aware. Cheers.

Comment: Remember, custom format is case sensitive. It should be `yyyy/dd/MM`, Not `yyyy/dd/mm`.

Comment: i am getting `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

Answer (score 1):

You mean how to get date without the time component? Use [DateTimePicker.Value.Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx)
But you need to format the output to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

@Shoban It looks like the question is tagged c# so here is the appropriate snipped
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx

```
public MyClass()
{
    // Create a new DateTimePicker
    DateTimePicker dateTimePicker1 = new DateTimePicker();
    Controls.Add(dateTimePicker1);
    MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString());

    dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
    MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var store = dtpDateTimePicker.Value.Date;
```

store can be anything entity object etc.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, like it

```
string fecha = dtFecha.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Datum = DateTime.Parse(DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```