# DateTimePicker Date formatting value

Tags: c#, datetime, format, datetimepicker

I am getting date value correctly from DateTimePicker using `DateTimePicker.Value`.

However I wish to format my date to be `YYYYMMDD` (*ex: "20151020"*). Is this possible please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get only the date value from a Windows Forms DateTimePicker control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138195/how-to-get-only-the-date-value-from-a-windows-forms-datetimepicker-control)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple formating can be achieved by using the following code.

```
DateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Answer (score 2):

[`DateTimePicker.Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx) returns `DateTime`, not a `string`. A `DateTime` does not have *any* implicit format. It just have date and time values. It's *textual* representation *can* have a format which is usually done with `ToString()` method like;

```
string myFormat = DateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Remember, there is no `YYYY` and `DD` as a [custom date and time format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx). They should be as [`yyyy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#yyyySpecifier) and [`dd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#ddSpecifier) since they are case sensitive.

Comment: nice point `. It's textual representation can have a format which is usually done with ToString() method like;`

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to have your result in string format:

```
string dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd";
string result = DateTimePicker.Value.ToString(dateFormat);
```

For other formats, here's the reference:

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/